# Fixed horizontal scrollbar in child element

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper that contains two children which each takes up 50% in width. They are equal in height which is higher than the parent. The parent handles this with overflow-y.

The right div could contain content that is wider than the divs width which is handled with overflow-x on the div. My problem is that I want the scrollbar to be fixed at the bottom of the parent div so it’s always visible.

Here is the html to illustrate the problem.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
    <p class="left-content-row">Left content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
    <p class="right-content-row">Right content</p>
  </div>
```

I have created a plunkr to show the setup and the problem

https://plnkr.co/edit/QkH0QT7bhUjKcntPjMtG?p=preview

Comment: you would only be able to do that if you had the vertical scroll handled separately for the left and right div (ie move the scroll from parent to children) or just put all the scroll onto the parent

Comment: ok. they content in the left and divs correlates but then I have to solve it with javascript I guess.

Comment: If it is tabular data - use tables and then perhaps you would then be able to use the datatables plugin to get the scrolling effects you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The real structure is a little bit more complex in the real code.

Comment: What about adding left padding to the parent for the width of the left column, then position that column absolutely. Then you can just sit the right column where it needs to be and have the scrolling on the parent meaning the left column will stay where it is.   You may then need a little js for making sure the right column is always as tall as the left column (so the vertical scrolling works)

Comment: That might be a solution. Thanks for the idea.